# What species is Captain Blue Bird?

Tags: rhythm-heaven

I'd like to ask about the “Blue Birds” minigame in the Nintendo DS videogame *Rhythm Heaven*.

The smaller Captain Blue Bird, who wears sunglasses, is training a troupe of blue bird soldiers who look like storks.  **What species of bird** is Captain Blue Bird?

[image]

Feel free to use material from the sequel game *Rhythm Heaven Megamix* if that helps answer.

If you have doubts that this minigame is off-topic for the site, [read the diary that you can obtain in game: in that, the blue bird complains that they have to learn to fly an airplane and to parachute rather than just fly with their wings.](https://rhythmheaven.fandom.com/wiki/Reading_Material_(Rhythm_Heaven)#Blue_Bird_Diary)

Comment: Doesn't this fall under the [anthropomorphic animals](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5117/101407) reason for ruling a question off-topic?

Comment: @DavidW https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10549/4918 says “If the animal's non-human nature has substantial narrative focus, then the story is probably on-topic”. Half of the linked diary is about how the blue bird isn't allowed to fly with their wings.

Comment: If it looks like a duck...

Comment: @Showsni she doesn't quack like a duck. She talks. She sings, in the English version of the game, “peck your beak” and “stretch out your neck”.